# Fork stdin to stdout & stderr?

Tags: stdout, stderr, tee, fork

I am wondering if it's possible to fork standard input to stdout & stderr? Something like this,

```
$ echo "hi" | fork > std.out 2> std.err
$ cat std.out
hi
$ cat std.err
hi
```

Or, am I missing something that will let me fork input to two different targets? The `tee` command seems like it is close to what I want, but I would prefer not to have to write to a file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to understand the classic "everything is a file" in Linux. The `tee` utility copies standard input to standard output and makes a copy to file(s). So identifying the file stderr writes to, `/dev/stderr`, allows stdin to be written to two files and re-directed, like below -

```bash
$ echo "hi" | tee /dev/stderr > test.out 2> test.err
$ cat test.out
hi
$ cat test.err
hi
```

Comment: Hum, it seems strange to write tee /dev/stderr 2> test.err instead of tee test.err. It works of course.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, when you redirect a fd more than once for output, zsh does the forking internally, so you'd do:

```
echo hi >&1 >&2
```

To output both to stdout and stderr.

Though, if you wanted to output it to both `test.out` and `test.err`, you'd do:

```
echo hi > test.out > test.err
```

instead.

On systems other than Linux based ones and Cygwin, you can do the same with

```
echo hi | tee /dev/stderr
```

On Linux and Cygwin, that's wrong though unless stderr happens to be opened on a pipe or tty as opening `/dev/stderr` opens the file pointed to by stderr (fd 2) anew, so for instance if stderr was being redirected to a log file, that would replace the log file with that `hi` line, and if stderr was opened to a socket, that would fail as sockets can't be *opened*.

Adding the `-a` option to `tee` (for *append* mode) can help with the case of a log file.

Another work around with shells with process substitution support is to use:

```
echo hi | tee >(cat >&2)
```

But that also comes with its own problems, like the fact that in some shells such as `bash`, that `cat` command is not waited for, so you can see this kind of problem:

```
$ bash -c 'echo hi | tee >(cat >&2); echo after >&2'
hi
after
hi
```

Where `echo after` is being run before `cat` has had time to write `hi`.